# icons missing for built in 2sxc actions

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a strange situation.  I have a DNN instance with more than one portal running on it.  I started up a new portal and when I add a 2sxc content app, the icons for the built in actions like add and edit are missing.  However, the other portals in the DNN instance have the icons.

You can see the blue action buttons but no icons in the following image from the site:

[image]

I have checked the rendered html on both sites and the icon button contains the same html:

```
<div><i class="icon-sxc-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Removing aria-hidden="true" does not make the icon appear.  I think that I must be missing an icon font on the site that is missing the icons, but I am not sure which one to use.

### EDIT 1

I noticed that font-awesome was not being loaded so i added the following to the header of the site:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?cdv=607" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But the icons are still missing

Anyone have some thoughts on why this icon is missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something is messing with the CSS which maps the icons to the buttons.

First just up-count the client-dependency number, my guess is it would fix everything.

Otherwise debug more using inspect-element to see how the other toolbars get their icon, and what is different with this instance.

[image]

Comment: thanks Daniel, I tried incrementing the client-dep number but that did not work.  This portal is using the POLO theme so I assume there is a conflicting css rule, I will have to dig in more to see what is going on.

Comment: if i inspect element and remove the <i class="icon-sxc-glasses">
</i> and replace it with any text value, that text value appears.  The icon itself is not redering.  Just to confirm, these are fontawsome icons?  I must be missing an import

Comment: 2sxc inpage contains an own icon set, because font-awesome is just way too large/heavy. It's mapped using inpage-icons.css and comes from a tiny font-file called inpage-icons.woff

Comment: I just updated the main post to show the connection between the tag and the css-class

Comment: thanks, the custom dnn theme was overriding the font family with something else.  Its working now